# How can I set a default value in a select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello I would like to set a default value for a select. Here is my HTML code :

```
<select id="myselect" name="select" method="post" class="form-control">
    <option value="England1" selected>"England</option>
</select>
```

And here is my javascript code :

```
alert($("#myselect").val());
```

But when I refresh the page I got 'undefined'

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: strange your code it's ok, if i run multiple time work alwys.

Comment: @JohnMaerlender Is your `javascript` code executing before the `DOM` has loaded? Try changing your `javascript` code to `$(function() { alert($("myselect").val()); });` or move your script below your `Html`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) If you want others to help you effectively. And don't forget to accept (and up-vote) an answer when it answers your question.

Comment: I can not make your code fail inside codesandbox no matter the order of the scripts or if it's waiting for DOM to load or not, the only way I can think of where it would fail would be if you're creating your html with js, and your `alert` code runs before that creation, you need to provide more details about your setup. Do you still have the problem after wrapping your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Try</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#">
        <select name="select" id="select">
            <option value="england">England</option>
            <option value="india" selected>India</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I did the same and it works fine, also you don't need the js over here !